# Did Siddartha have a back problem?

Tags: the-buddha, pain

in Week 3 Mindfulness of Emotions an online course at:http://www.insightmeditationcenter.org/books-articles/articles/introduction-to-meditation-transcripts/all/1/

Gil Fronsdal says "... the Buddha had a bad back. You wouldn’t believe it with his good posture, but he had a bad back and sometimes he couldn’t give his Dharma talk, so he’d lie down instead and have one of his senior disciples give a talk."

Anyone know where he might have got this information from?

Answer (score 4):

> So the Blessed One, putting on his robe and taking up his bowl & outer
>   robe, went together with a community of monks to the reception hall.
>   On arrival he washed his feet, entered the hall, and sat with his back
>   to the central post, facing east. The community of monks washed their
>   feet, entered the hall, and sat with their backs to the western wall,
>   facing east, ranged around the Blessed One. The Kapilavatthu Sakyans
>   washed their feet, entered the hall, and sat with their backs to the
>   eastern wall, facing west, ranged around the Blessed One. Then the
>   Blessed One — having spent most of the night instructing, urging,
>   rousing, & encouraging the Kapilavatthu Sakyans with a Dhamma talk —
>   said to Ven. Ananda, "Ananda, speak to the Kapilavatthu Sakyans about
>   the person who follows the practice for one in training. [2] My back
>   aches. I will rest it." - **Sekha-patipada Sutta : MN 53**

http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.053.than.html

Comment: whether this was a chronic condition is unknown.